# SIP Websocket/WebRTC-UDP прокси

Tags: websocket, прокси, sip, webrtc

Есть АТС-провайдер, предоставляющий SIP линии по UDP. Нужно прямо в браузере на Javascript, сделать звонилку, то есть чтобы, в том числе, говорить в браузере.

Как я понял, из браузера совершать звонки (работать с аудиопотоком) в таком случае нельзя, поскольку браузер поддерживает другой протокол — вебсокет или WebRTC, не знаю точно что лучше. По UDP к АТС можно подключиться только настольным ПО типа Microsip или Zoiper.

Для решения этой проблемы, как я понял, нужно иметь свой SIP-прокси сервер, который будет уметь на входе работать с браузером по вебсокету или вебртс, и транслировать это в UDP SIP-серверу провайдера, ну и наоборот, UDP от провайдера транслировать в Вебсокет/Вебртс клиенту (браузеру).

Есть Astersik, Freeswitch, Kamalio и прочие SIP-серверы, но как через них (или не через них) сделать просто ретранслятор Websocket-UDP, я уже несколько дней не могу понять.

На данный момент есть vps с Ubuntu 22.04, если кто-то имел опыт в реализации такого решения, подскажите пожалуйста, или предоставьте ссылку.

---

**Обновление**

На данный момент, наверное наиболее подходящие статьи, которые я нашёл эти:

1. [Сделать Freeswitch как прокси](https://www.plivo.com/docs/sip-trunking/interconnection-guides/freeswitch) (тут используется термин trunk, я обычно гуглил по термину gateway)
2. [Подключиться к Freeswitch по WebRTC](https://asterisk-pbx.ru/wiki/artikle/webrtc_freeswitch)

Буду пробывать по отдельности, и в связке

Comment: В браузерах есть WebRTC. Возможно, кто-нибудь уже делал прокси между SIP и WebRTC

Comment: @andreymal, ну WebRTC, насколько я понял, всё равно предполагает использование Websocket

Comment: WebRTC не имеет никакого отношения к Websocket. Точнее, можно сделать signaling через Websocket, но можно попытаться и без вебсокета через какой-нибудь ajax

Comment: Самое сложное в поставленной задаче - перекодирование DTLS/SRTP RTP трафика от WebRTC в обычный RTP (даже с SRTP) трафик обычной SIP телефонии.